# Forecasting seasonal time series in R with weekly data

Tags: r, regression, time-series, seasonality

I have a data set that contains weekly orders for a product. Since the data is a time series, I have the following line:

```
orders.ts <-ts(product_data.data$ProductName, start = c(2015,6), end= c(2016,37), freq = 52)
```

I set the frequency equal to 52 since the orders are on a weekly basis. I am trying to forecast and account for seasonality, but the built-in seasonality function gives me 52 "seasons"/beta coefficients when I try the following:

```
nValid <- 10
nTrain <-length(orders.ts) - nValid
train.ts<-window(orders.ts, start= c(2015,6), end = c(2015,nTrain+1))
valid.ts<-window(orders.ts, start= c(2015,nTrain+1), end = c(2016,nTrain+nValid+1))
train.lm <- tslm(train.ts ~ season)
```

How can I account for monthly (and not weekly) seasonality? I only want coefficients for 12 seasons/months.

Comment: See http://robjhyndman.com/hyndsight/forecasting-weekly-data/